How can I find the integer numbers a, b, c so the total distances get minimum?
Let two points ptA = {1, 2, 3} and
ptB = {-2, 5, -3}. Find the point ptM on the plane has the equation $z = 0$ so that total distance from the point ptM to two points ptA and ptB minimum. I tried
Clear["Global`*"]
ptA = {1, 2, 3};
ptB = {-2, 5, -3};
ptM = {x, y, z};
planeEq = z == 0;
distanceA = EuclideanDistance[ptA, ptM];
distanceB = EuclideanDistance[ptB, ptM];
totalDistance = distanceA + distanceB;
solution = Minimize[{totalDistance, planeEq}, {x, y, z}];
ptM /. solution[[2]]


{-(1/2), 7/2, 0}

If ptA = {a, b, c}, $a, b, c$ are integer numbers and in the interval $[1,5]$ or $[-5,-1]$ and
ptB = {-2, 5, -3}. How can I find $a, b, c$, and $M(x, y, z)$ lies on the plane $z = 0$ so that $MA + MB$ minmum?

ptM is the intersection point of the plane $z=0$ and the line segment $AB$. Do you want to avoid using this kind of geometric interpretation?

@A.Kato I have just edited my question.

The point m on z==0 that has minimal distance b-m is: {-2,5,0}. And the point with integer coordinates that has minimal distance from m is: a==m

NMinimize does the work:
Clear["Global`*"];ptA = {a, b, c};ptB = {-2, 5, -3};
ptM = {x, y, z};planeEq = z == 0;distanceA = 
EuclideanDistance[ptA, ptM];distanceB = 
EuclideanDistance[ptB, ptM];totalDistance = distanceA + distanceB;
solution =  NMinimize[{totalDistance, planeEq && 
x \[Element] Integers && y \[Element] Integers && 
z \[Element] Integers,  a \[Element] Integers && b \[Element] Integers && 
c \[Element] Integers && a <= 5 && a >= 1 && b <= 5 && b >= 1 && 
c >= 1 && c <= 5}, {a, b, c, x, y, z}, 
Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "ScalingFactor" -> 1}, 
MaxIterations -> 300]


{5.01976, {a -> 1, b -> 5, c -> 1, x -> 0, y -> 5, z -> 0}}

Addition. In order to answer the additional question of the OP "Can you find all triples $(a,b,c)$ and $(x,y,z)$? ", the following can be used.
FindInstance[{totalDistance == totalDistance /. {a -> 1, b -> 5, 
c -> 1, x -> 0, y -> 5, z -> 0}, planeEq, x \[Element] Integers, 
y \[Element] Integers, z \[Element] Integers, 
a \[Element] Integers, b \[Element] Integers, c \[Element] Integers,
 a <= 5, a >= 1,  b <= 5, b >= 1 && c >= 1, c <= 5}, {a, b, c, x, y,z}, Integers, 200]

It seems that set is not finite.
Addition 2. Indeed, the result of
Reduce[{totalDistance == totalDistance /. {a -> 1, b -> 5, c -> 1, 
x -> 0, y -> 5, z -> 0}, planeEq, x \[Element] Integers, 
  y \[Element] Integers, z \[Element] Integers, a \[Element] Integers,
   b \[Element] Integers, c \[Element] Integers, a <= 5, a >= 1,  b <= 5, b >= 1 && c >= 1, c <= 5}, {a, b, c, x, y, z}, Integers]

describes that infinite set.

My question is $a$, $b$, $c$ integer numbers.

How can I find $a, b, c $?

@minhthien_2016: See the edited answer, whhere 1a,b,c` are taken into consideration.

Can you find all triples $(a,b,c)$ and $(x,y,z)$?

@minhthien_2016: See the addition to my answer.
